# Do mountain biking questions belong here

Tags: discussion, scope

So, the title says it all. If I wanted to ask questions about mountain biking, should they be posted here or on the cycling SE?

Comment: I think a question specifically about bikes (Say what spares should I carry for back country  MTB trip) would be better answered on bicycles. A question about the outdoor environment (say "Should I carry an emergency beacon on a back country MTB trip) might be better suited to this site (The latter would possibly be closed as off topic on Bicycles).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think for both this and indoor climbing, we have to ask which groups share the most in common.

In this case, I think mountain biking will have more in common and share more commonalities with other biking activities than with other TGO activities and thus should go on biking

Comment: Agreed: Gear, bike maintenance, bike racks, etc. etc. all go into Mountain Biking and share a lot the same with other cycling.

Answer (score 0):

While I totally agree this question fits better into biking.SE, the same is true for so many things we considered on topic (e.g. all kinds of animal related stuff). We even declared [rail biking as on topic](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/892/would-railbiking-be-on-topic/896#896).